# Chrome and fullscreen api: resize element to fill the fullscreen window not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dojo, webkit, fullscreen

Using the following code:

```
function _launchIntoFullscreen (pElement) {
    if(pElement.requestFullscreen) {
        pElement.requestFullscreen();
    } else if(pElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        pElement.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if(pElement.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
        pElement.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    } else if(pElement.msRequestFullscreen) {
        pElement.msRequestFullscreen();
    }
}
```

I can switch a single element to fullscreen mode, e.g. for a dijit.form.ContentPane named "canvas"

```
_launchIntoFullscreen(canvas.domNode);
```

works fine, but unfortunately with Chrome the element is not resized to fill all of the fullscreen window. The size remains the same and it is centered on screen.

I have added the following to the CSS:

```
:-webkit-full-screen {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: none;
}
```

but the only change is the position, which is now the upper left corner, but the size is still the same.

Additional information: The structure of the page is

```
<div class="page-wrapper" style="width:100%; height:100%;">
  <div id="toolbar" class="toolbar"></div>
  <div id="borderContainer" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer" design="sidebar" persist="false" gutters="true" style="min-width: 1em; min-height: 1px; z-index: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0px 0px 32px 0px;">
    <div id="projectPane" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" extractContent="false" preventCache="false" preload="false" refreshOnShow="false" region="left" splitter="true" maxSize="Infinity" doLayout="true" style="width: 220px; padding: 0px;">
      <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/TabContainer" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0px;">
        <div id="treeParent" class="treeParent" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" title="Palette"  data-dojo-props="selected:true" style="padding:0px;"></div>
        <div id="onlineParent" class="treeParent" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" title="Online"  data-dojo-props="selected:false" style="padding:0px;"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="workAreaContainer" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" extractContent="false" preventCache="false" preload="false" refreshOnShow="false" region="center" splitter="false" maxSize="Infinity" doLayout="true" style="padding: 0px;">
      <div id="workArea" class="workArea" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/TabContainer" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0px;" data-dojo-props="tabPosition: 'right-h'">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="bottom" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/TabContainer" extractContent="false" preventCache="false" preload="false" refreshOnShow="false" region="bottom" splitter="true" maxSize="Infinity" doLayout="true" style="width: 100%; height: 10%; padding: 0px;">
      <div id="log" class="log" title="Log" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" extractContent="false" preventCache="false" preload="false" refreshOnShow="false" maxSize="Infinity" doLayout="false" style="height:100%;padding:0px;overflow:auto;"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="properties" class="properties" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" extractContent="false" preventCache="false" preload="false" refreshOnShow="false" region="right" splitter="true" minSize=0 maxSize="Infinity" doLayout="false" style="width:250px;padding: 0px;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

canvas is created dynamically:

```
var lTabContainer = dijit.byId("workArea");
var canvas = new ContentPane({
            title: this.keys.pouname, //"Main",
            //id: "surface",
            class: "surfaceX",
            extractContent: "false",
            preventCache: "false",
            preload: "false",
            refreshOnShow: "false",
            maxSize: "Infinity",
            doLayout: "false",
            "data-dojo-props": "selected:true",
            style: "padding: 0px;"
});
lTabContainer.addChild(canvas);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

In Firefox everything behaves as expected even without the CSS.

Thanks a lot for giving me insight into a solution.

Comment: I have tried this and it works for me, also in Chrome. I used containerNode instead of divNode. You can also try to manually call the resize() function of your pane after webkitRequestFullscreen().

Comment: Tried to use containerNode instead of domNode (was a typo in my post). Also tried to resize the CP, does not work either.

I also tried some other elements in my app (other ContentPanes, a Tree control), did not resize either. Could you please post the code that works for you. There must be a difference (e.g. with the CSS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example html that for me works both in Firefox and Chrome. Try adding the style "width: 100%; height: 100%" to the ContentPane that will go full screen.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body class="claro">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/resources/dojo.css"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">

    <script>
        require([
          "dijit/layout/ContentPane",
          "dojo/dom-construct",
          "dojo/on",
          "dojo/keys",
          "dojo/domReady!"
        ], function(ContentPane, domConstruct, on, keys) {
              var pane = new ContentPane({style: "background-color: green; width: 100%; height: 100%"});
              var div = domConstruct.toDom("<div>Some content here</div>");
              domConstruct.place(div, pane.containerNode);

              pane.placeAt("content");

              on(pane, "click", function() {
                _launchIntoFullscreen(pane.containerNode);
              });
        });

        function _launchIntoFullscreen (pElement) {
            if(pElement.requestFullscreen) {
                pElement.requestFullscreen();
            } else if(pElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {
                pElement.mozRequestFullScreen();
            } else if(pElement.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
                pElement.webkitRequestFullscreen();
            } else if(pElement.msRequestFullscreen) {
                pElement.msRequestFullscreen();
            }
        }
    </script>

    <div style="width: 300px; height: 100px;">
        <div id="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="othercontent">Some other content</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The example works, but setting width and height to 100% in my case did not work before switching to fullscreen mode. installed a handler to get notified about a fullscreen change and then setting width and height worked

Answer (score 0):

It seems, the enclosing dijit Layout Containers prevented the element to stretch to width and height 100%.

The solution I found was not obvious for me, but it works:

1. install a handler notified on fullscreen mode change
2. in the handler set width and height to 100% when fullscreen mode is activated.

So I changed my function _launchIntoFullscreen to

```
function _launchIntoFullscreen (pElement,pFunction) {
    if(pElement.requestFullscreen) {
        pElement.onfullscreenchange = function(pEvent) {
            if(pFunction) {
                pFunction(document.fullscreenElement);
            }
        }
        pElement.requestFullscreen();
    } else if(pElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        pElement.onmozfullscreenchange = function(pEvent) {
            if(pFunction) {
                pFunction(document.mozFullScreenElement);
            }
        }
        pElement.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if(pElement.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
        pElement.onwebkitfullscreenchange = function(pEvent) {
            if(pFunction) {
                pFunction(document.webkitFullscreenElement);
            }
        }
        pElement.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    } else if(pElement.msRequestFullscreen) {
        pElement.onmsfullscreenchange = function(pEvent) {
            if(pFunction) {
                pFunction(document.msFullscreenElement);
            }
        }
        pElement.msRequestFullscreen();
    }
}
```

and invoke the function as

```
_launchIntoFullscreen(canvas.domNode,lang.hitch(this,function(pElem) {
                    if(pElem) {
                        pElem.style.width = "100%";
                        pElem.style.height = "100%"
                    }
                }));
```

This solution has a drawback, in that the users sees (for a very short moment), that the element is resized after switching to fullscreen mode